# Как получить референс на кнопку нажатую и обрабатываемую в @click в Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue3

Есть кнопка с вложенным в нее svg:

```
<template v-for="row in objekts" :key="row.id">
  <tr class="table__objem-row">
    <td v-for="(td, i) in tableStructureVisible" :key="i">
      {{ row[td.field] }}
    <button class="btn-arrowed" @click="hideAllDetails">
      <svg width="24" height="24" role="img" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M7.41,8.58L12,13.17L16.59,8.58L18,10L12,16L6,10L7.41,8.58Z"></path>
      </svg>
    </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

В функцию приходит event, у которого target не кнопка, а вложенный в неё svg.
Мне же нужно референс именно на кнопку.
Решил задачу через path:

```
hideAllDetails(e) {
  // удаляем window и document из массива, они не работают с contains
  const btn = e.path.slice(0,-2).find(el => el.classList.contains('btn-arrowed')); 
  btn.classList.add("table__details-row-shown");
  setTimeout(() => {
    btn.classList.remove("table__details-row-shown");
  }, 1500);
}
```

Но что-то мне подсказывает, что есть способ проще.
И вообще очень хочется понять почему событие on-click стоит на button, а вызывается оно с элемента svg, который вложен в button.

Comment: Может  это `@ref`?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду массив this.$refs ?

Comment: @merlinby создай булевую переменную в дате и показывай кнопки через `v-if` + эта переменная. В методе меняй её значение на `false`. Всё

Comment: А зачем вам референс на кнопку?

Comment: @AleksandrBelous Не понял как это решает мою задачу. Плюс этих кнопок может быть толпа, т.к. находятся в динамически формируемой таблице. Т.е. придется заводить не переменную, а массив, каким-то образом идентифицировать кнопки по каком-нибудь ключу.

Comment: @Kain Для того чтобы переключить (toggle) у нее один класс на определенное время:

Comment: @merlinby каким образом вы динамически формируете таблицу?

Comment: @AleksandrBelous через v-for, подставляя данные из массива. Если это важно, то у каждой строчки есть ствой уникальный id (не индекс, а имеено id)

Comment: @merlinby а что вам нужно? в чем проблема удалять кнопки, удаляя нужный элемент массива? у вас генерируются элементы, пишете такую конструкцию `@click="removeElement(item.id)"` и в методе удаляет элемент из массива.

Comment: @AleksandrBelous да, вы правы. Для удаления элементов из массива я так бы и поступил. Но мне нужен референс на дом элемент определенной кнопки, чтобы на 1 секунду навесить ей определенный класс. Сейчас более подродно напишу в вопросе свой код.

Comment: @merlinby для анимаций есть отдельный тэг `transition`, который делает это за вас.https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html

Comment: Как сказали выше, есть transition. Так же вы можете временно добавить класс без доступа к элементу https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Comment: Насчет почему target - это svg. onclick работает на всех потомков внутри элемента, на который повешен. Вы можете добавить следующие стили для элементов внутри кнопки, чтобы они не получали событий: pointer-events: none;  -webkit-touch-callout: none;  -webkit-user-select: none;  -khtml-user-select: none;  -moz-user-select: none;  -ms-user-select: none;  -o-user-select: none;  user-select: none;

Comment: @Kain спасибо огромное. pointer-events: none; решает проблему и в event.target попадает имеено button.

Comment: @AleksandrBelous ваша помощь натолкнула меня на мысль реализовать все через динамический класс с привязкой к массиву состояний. Спасибо!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В результате помощи пользователей **@AleksandrBelous** и **@Kain** (спасибо им огромное) сделал 2 варианта оптимизации решения поставленной задачи:

1. При добавлении стиля `pointer-events: none` для `svg` в `event.target` попадает только кнопка и дальше уже можно оперировать с ней без поиска по массиву `event.path`. Функция обработки события будет такой:

```
hideAllDetails(event) {
    const btn = event.target;
    btn.classList.add("table__details-row-shown");
    setTimeout(() => {
        btn.classList.remove("table__details-row-shown");
    }, 1500);
}
```

2. Вариант с использованием массива состояний:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      tableHideAllBtnStatus: [],
    }
  }
}
```

```
<template v-for="row in objekts" :key="row.id">
  <tr class="table__objem-row">
    <td v-for="(td, i) in tableStructureVisible" :key="i">
      {{ row[td.field] }}
    <button 
       class="btn-arrowed" 
       :class=" { 'table__details-row-shown' : tableHideAllBtnStatus.includes(row.id) } "
       @click="hideAllDetails(row.id)">
      <svg width="24" height="24" role="img" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M7.41,8.58L12,13.17L16.59,8.58L18,10L12,16L6,10L7.41,8.58Z"></path>
      </svg>
    </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

```
hideAllDetails(rowId) {
    this.tableHideAllBtnStatus.push(rowId)
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.tableHideAllBtnStatus = this.tableHideAllBtnStatus.filter(e => e !== rowId);
    }, 1500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
  <button
    v-for="(btn, idx) in buttons"
    :key="btn.id"
    class="button"
    @click="removeElement(btn.id)"
  >
    {{ btn.text + btn.id }}
  </button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      buttons: [
        {
          id: '1',
          text: 'button',
        },
        {
          id: '2',
          text: 'button',
        },
        {
          id: '3',
          text: 'button',
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    removeElement(id) {
      const idx = this.buttons.findIndex((el) => el.id === id);
      this.buttons.splice(idx, 1);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```